# why do my ul lists have a massive gap?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to sort out html lists styling but i've no idea why this is happening.

So see here: http://www.gamingonlinux.com/articles/fester-mudd-adventure-game-released-for-linux.1871

My UL html lists seem to have a massive gap above them, how can I remove that?

Comment: Please include the concerned code into your question. A link _will_ change sooner or later and then your question will become irrelevant.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because by default, `ul`s have a `margin-top` of `40px` (in Chrome, different browsers vary). Set `margin: 0px` on your `ul` and that will fix it:

```
ul {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Default in what browser? That information is a tiny little bit misleading. Yes, there is a default margin in all modern browsers, but it's not `40px` everywhere. btw: The [default CSS 2.1 style sheet provided by W3C claims `1.12em`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html).

Comment: @Zeta In Chrome, added a disclaimer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Set the following styes:

```
ul{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Your browser is adding UL margins as default - you need to reset the default browser `CSS`

Answer (score 1):

by adding `margin:0` to your `.content-list` rule declaration.

BTW, you can't have a `<br />` in `<ul>` tag. That's invalid markup

Answer (score 0):

Your UL content-list has a margin of 14 if you inspect the element in your browser developer tools specifically in chrome the side tool metrics will show your spacing values. Just set margin:0px; for that UL style and that gap will be gone.